# Change event ending while changing its' position by dragging it in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create dynamic duration of currently dragged event. How could I achieve this?

I've tried setting event end via `setEnd` in `eventPositioned` with proper checks, since `setEnd` fires again `eventPositioned`.

```
function eventPositoned(info) {
  const currentEnd = info.event.end.getTime();
  // It is not dependent of start-end
  // Returns epoch
  const newEnd = getNewEnd(info.event);
  if (currentEnd !== newEnd) {
    info.event.setEnd(newEnd);
  }
}
```

It works, but when dragging is finished (on drop). While I'm dragging, size of event stays same as old size.